# generate matches in a tournament

Tags: java, spring, algorithm

How to generate matches in a tournament I have a tournament, participants are being added to it. There is a match that should consist of two participants. How to take participants from a tournament and generate matches from them.

```
@Entity
public class Participant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "participant_id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nick_name")
    private String nickName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_fk_id")
    private Tournament tournament;
*gets,Sets
```

Tournament

```
@Entity
public class Tournament {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "tournament_id")
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tournament", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<TournamentMatch> tournamentMatchSet = new HashSet<>();

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tournament", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Participant> participantList = new ArrayList<>();
```

TournamentMatch

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mach")
public class TournamentMatch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "mach_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalDate startTime;

    @Column(name = "finisch_time")
    private LocalDate finischTime;

    private BigDecimal scores;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_fk_id")
    private Tournament tournament;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "participant_two_fk_id")
    private Participant participantTwo;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "participant_one_fk_id")
    private Participant participantOne;
```

I cannot understand the algorithm for solving the problem.

I have a list with participants in the tournament
do you need to distribute them in pairs and add them to the match? or do you need to create a method that only adds two participants to the match?

Answer (score 0):

Add all participants in a list. Iterate through the list and picking 2 participants at a time and creating a match for it. you can combine all matches in a list and store them for history. You filter the participant's list by remove participants who lost the match until only one is left. That participant can be the winner.

Answer (score 0):

The matching algorithm depends on what you want to do. Simplest is to randomly pair participants (sort participants list randomly, then pair them). You might have a left-over participant which you could create a "bye" match from, or omit.

More complicated would be to "seed" the participants (in skill order, or order added to the tournament) and pair highest seed to lowest seed, second highest to second lowest, etc.

I'm not sure I follow your question completely, but I think you would both need a function to pair participants and I method to add them to a match and persist the matches.

Follow-up questions would be:

- Do you want additional "rounds" of matches?
- Should they follow a particular bracket structure (ie. Single Elimination or Round Robin)